# SwiftUI: Custom Rating View For Each Image URL

Tags: swiftui

I was wondering if someone can help me solve this problem. I have the following rating view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RatingView: View {
    @Binding var rating: Int
    
    var label = ""
    var maxRating = 5
    
    var offImage: Image?
    var onImage = Image(systemName: "star.fill")
    
    var offColor = Color.gray
    var onColor = Color.yellow
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            if label.isEmpty == false {
                Text(label)
            }
            
            ForEach(1..<maxRating + 1, id: \.self){ number in
                image(for: number)
                    .foregroundColor(number > rating ? offColor : onColor)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        rating = number
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func image(for number: Int) -> Image {
        if number > rating {
            return offImage ?? onImage
        } else {
            return onImage
        }
    }
}

struct RatingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RatingView(rating: .constant(4))
    }
}
```

I wanted to have a custom rating for each image displayed in the ContenView, which is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var pictureURL = DbHelper().getPictures()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authenticator: Authenticator
    
    @State private var rating: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List(pictureURL, id: \.self) { photo in
            VStack{
                if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: photo), scale: 10.0)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
                RatingView(rating: $rating)
            }
        }
        Button("Logout") {
            authenticator.logout()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(Authenticator())
    }
}
```

This code displays the view but when I click on a start, all of the ratings change to that value. I eventually want to add to a database, for specified user who is logged in, the rating, and image URL associated with that rating.

Any hints on how to go about this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your loop, all of your rating views bind to the same `$rating` state variable. So, if you have five images and ratings views for each, if you tap on the first one, that changes `ContentView`'s `rating` value, and that change is then reflected in the other four.

To have individual ratings, you'll need some way of associating a rating with a picture URL. Depending on how you end up modelling your data, that could involve replacing `pictureURL`, an array of URL strings, with an array of objects, each of which contains the URL and a bindable rating that applies to that user.

There are other ways of structuring that data, depending on how your final model needs to be structured, but the key will always be that the rating you pass to your `RatingView` will need to apply to the current URL and no others.

Comment: Ok, I made a struct in my Database class and returned a struct containing a picture URL and a rating with value 0. I was wondering how I would pass a different value of rating for each picture. Would it be an onClick event in the RatingView class? What I am saying is that I do not know how to create an array of structs before I loop through it to show up in the ContentView. Sorry if this doesn't make sense I am kind of lost.